# Google static map image with link to Google iframe

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fancybox

I am trying to display a google static map, which when clicked, will open up a larger iframe, where the user can pan, zoom, etc.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/thong/Q4FE7/)

**Code below:**

```
<div>
    <a class="various fancybox.iframe" title="Whitehouse - USA" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=&amp;daddr=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+White+House,+Washington,+DC+20500&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=Ca3jx5Eq6BcjFQ6IUQIdG4Ro-ynPaZnjvLe3iTGGOSyaFzTP2g&amp;sll=38.897678,-77.036517&amp;sspn=0.009644,0.01443&amp;g=1600+Pennsylvania+Avenue+Northwest,+Washington,+DC&amp;mra=ls&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=38.89768,-77.036519&amp;spn=0.008016,0.013733&amp;z=16&amp;output=embed">

        <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+White+House,+Washington,+DC+20500&markers=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+White+House,+Washington,+DC+20500&size=300x300&sensor=false">

    </a>
</div>
```

I have tried to look for the non-javascript documentation relating to the iframe,but haven't come across anything. I would like to add the following *to the iframe*:

**Center on the marker** - The JSFiddle appears centered, but the exact same code run on the production site renders an iframe with the marker appearing in the top left.

**Remove the marker label "B"**

**Input my own coordinates from my database** - for example... do the same for New York City, Chicago, etc.. However, I have tried changing the `daddr` (destination address), but am unsure what the other variable stand for (i.e. sll, sspn, g, mra, ll, etc.)

**Get directions - insert starting point, and get directions to pre-determined destination**

Comment: what does this have to do with fancybox? does the map display correctly in fancybox? .... just wonder if this is a fancybox related issue or simple a google map / iframe issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### At first a explanation of the parameters you need:

- **`f`**
  has to be **`d`** for directions
- **`saddr`**
  the start-address, may be a string(would be geolocated) or a latLng
- **`daddr`**
  the destination-address, may be a string(would be geolocated) or a latLng
- **`ll`**
  where to center the map(latlng) .when ommited, the map will be centered based on the markers
- **`z`**
  the zoom of the map. When ommitted the map will be zoomed based on the direction
- **`output`**
  has to be `embed` for iframe

A detailed list and explanation of the parameters you'll find at http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters

**However: you should note that none of the parameters is a part of any official API, it may change every day**

---

### The issues:

1. **Center on the marker:**
   the marker could not be centered, because the iframe isn't visible when the map starts loading, unable to determine the size of the iframe . You could use a workaround:

   First load a dummy-page into the iframe, when the fancybox is open, load the map.

   This can be done by adding this to the fancybox-options:

   ```
   beforeLoad: function(){
     //store the original href for later use
    this.oldhref=this.href;
     //replace the href with some dummy-page
    this.href='wait.htm';
    return true;
   },
   afterLoad:function(){
     //load the originally requested page to the iframe
    $('.fancybox-iframe').attr('src',this.oldhref);
   }
   ```
2. **Remove the marker label "B"**
   there is no option to remove the B, all you can to is replace it with an **A** .
   Therefore you must set the marker as the marker for the start-destination (saddr)
3. **Input my own coordinates from my database**
   apply the coordinates to saddr or daddr(depending on what it should be, start or destination)
4. **Get directions - insert starting point, and get directions to pre-determined destination**
   see 3.

---

Finally: you should consider to create a own map using the Maps-Javascript-API to get a map that you can handle yourself.

Comment: I am seeing that, when in directions mode ("f=d"), the "ll" parameter seems to be ignored. Anyone know how to force a directions map to center on a spot other than the center of the directions bound?