# HTML - turn specific google maps link to map inside an iframe

Tags: html, google-maps, dictionary, iframe, hyperlink

On a map I am working on, there are markers that show an iframe on mouseover. I am currently using `http://maps.google.com/?q=[% VARIABLE %]` to create links that navigate to variable places. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212871/google-static-map-image-with-link-to-google-iframe) post, it'd be nice to have my iframe simultaneously display a little map. Is it possible to use this changing link to directly show a map frame?

Here's a snippet of code I've been trying to do this with (plain HTML):

```
  <head>
   <style>
     #map {
      height: 400px;
      width: 100%;
      }
   </style>
  </head>
   <p>This is, among other countries, where the language can be found:</p>
<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=[% "MAPREF" %]"> 
Click here to locate [% "Sprache" %] on Google Maps.</a><p> (Keep in mind that only the first entry is shown.)</p>
   <div id="map"></div>
   <script>
     function initMap() {
      var uluru = {lat: 50.115017, lng: 8.634350}; 
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
      });
     }
   </script>
   <script async defer
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&callback=initMap">
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Note that currently, latitude and longitude are in use. While that would require to edit the coordinates of every single iframe, instead I could use the variable link to reference each complementary country code (which are saved in a text file that I can reference in the HTML). [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659191/how-to-open-google-map-link-in-iframe) describes a resembling problem, only that this method is useless in this case (as every marker has its designated data stored in a file). While it wouldn't matter if the displayed map is a static image or a clickable and zoomable frame, one of either would be great.